# how to highlight rows using dataframe and python based on value in a cell?

Tags: python, dataframe, highlight

I want to highlight records in the dataframe and csv files based on the value on a cell ?

i tried to  create a function and apply this function on the dataframe but it did not highlight any record.

[image]

the output must be :

[image]

code:

```
def_test_twtr_preds= pd.read_excel(path,names=col_names)


    def highlight_sentiment(status):
        if status == "Positive":
            return ['background-color: yellow']
        else:
            return ['background-color: white']
    
    def_test_twtr_preds.style.apply(highlight_sentiment,axis =1)
```

where is the error ??

Comment: Could you please provide sample data, as well as the expected output, in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works (demonstrated with synthetic data):

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "status": ["Negative", "Positive", "Positive"]})

def highlight_sentiment(row):
    if row["status"] == "Positive":
        return ['background-color: yellow'] * len(row)
    else:
        return ['background-color: white'] * len(row)
    
df.style.apply(highlight_sentiment, axis=1)
```

The output is:

[image]

To export to Excel, do the following:

```
df = df.style.apply(highlight_sentiment, axis=1)
df.to_excel("my_file.xlsx")
```

Comment: And how to export this highlight because i tried and it display  `Styler` object has no  attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: Export to what? CSV, as a format, doesn't support highlighting (it doesn't have any kind of style).

Comment: so can i export to excel i think it have highlight

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that can be you are not sending the input argument `status` when calling the function.

```
def_test_twtr_preds.style.apply(highlight_sentiment("positive"),axis =1)
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it still nothing is highlighted